# Select Table while in one schema from another Schema

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am writing code in a schema and I am looking to pull in a table from another schema. I have access to the other schema, however I can not grant permission to tables in that schema.

I have seen previous code which uses an '@' statement, e.g `Select * from X.Tablename@Y.K`

My question is I suppose what do the X, Y and K represent?

I tried the following code but it did not work:
`select * from tablename@schemaname`

The error message says there is issues with the connection, so I don't think I'm using the @ function correctly. I could not find anthing on it.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you have one database with two schemas.

If you are in SCHEMA_1 and you want to access TABLE_B in SCHEMA_2, then you write

```
select * from SCHEMA_2.TABLE_B
```

Now suppose SCHEMA_3 is in another database and has TABLE_C. To access TABLE_C you need a database link. The database link connects you to the other database as a specific user.

Suppose database link DB_REMOTE_3 connects you directly as SCHEMA_3; in that case you can write

```
select * from TABLE_C@DB_REMOTE_3
```

On the other hand, if database link DB_REMOTE_4 connects you to SCHEMA_4 in the other database, then you need to specify the schema as well as the database link.

```
select * from SCHEMA_3.TABLE_C@DB_REMOTE_3
```

Best regards,
Stew Ashton

Comment: Great thanks for your help Stew

Answer (score 1):

Ohh, In your case you will need to create the `DB link` and use it with @

```
create database link anotherschemalink connect to <another schema name> identified by <another schema password> using '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<hostname>)(PORT=<port>))   (CONNECT_DATA=(service=<service name>)))';
```

You can see `tnsnames.ora` for this connection data.

Now, you will be able to query another schema table using:

```
SELECT * FROM <ANOTHER SCHEMA TABLE NAME>@anotherschemalink;
```

Note: Your current user must have the `CREATE DATABASE LINK` system privilege.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In your example, X is the other schema and Y.K would be a DB link to another database.  If the other schema is in the same database you would not use the '@'.

What you probably want is this.

> select * from schemaname.tablename

I hope this helps.